# Define List<String> property in WPF UserControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls, attributes

I have created a `UserControl` which has several properties. When I add the user control in to WPF application it will display those properties in the Visual Studio Property Window.

But I have a property called `UserList` which is a `List<String>` type. That property is also displayed in the Property Window with hint text "(collection)" and button with three dots. When I click on that button it will show a dialog box, which can add some values to the `UserList` variable. But that part of the window is not enabled.

So how can I enable that part. Is there any special things that I have to do for my `UserList` property?

This is how my property definition looks:

```
    private List<String> dataSources = new List<String>();
    [Description("Users"), Category("Time Line")]
    public List<string> UserList
    {
        get { return dataSources; }
        set { dataSources = value; }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your question is.  Do you want help creating a dialog box?

Comment: @DanPuzey Thankx for the response. What i want is let user to add values to the UserList attribute through attribute window.

Comment: Check this screenshot. I want to enable that window area. https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B9KHl-VNES7QTkJQYUtoZnhWeVU

Comment: Keep in mind that the generated output would be XAML. How do you expect that XAML to look like? I'm asking this because - although there is a way to declare lists of strings in XAML - the property editor doesn't seem to know this by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, but I think this method does not work on Lists. But any way, `Collection` can be converted into a `List`.

```
private Collection<String> dataSources = new Collection<String>();
[Description("Data Sources"), Category("Time Line")]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public Collection<DataSourceModel> DataSources
{    
    get { return dataSources; }
    set { dataSources = value; }
}
```